# Trying to understand composite statements?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Note I'm not that far past Calculus and into proofs and logic, so forgive me if this is all obvious stuff. I'd appreciate any advice you have for me.

As I was reviewing the chapter in my book on logic I started to think about statements in terms of sets. Any statement can have two values, either true or false. So a statement P can be thought of as a variable pulling from a domain T={f,t}. If you have a composite statement C it is also a variable pulling from a range T={f,t} involving component statements P, Q, and R, each pulling from the set T as well, you might make a truth table for it. On the left you'd have the component statements with all their unique truth value combinations, and on the right you'd have the truth value of the composite statement that results from the various truth value combinations.

Now to me this looks exactly like an input/output table, with elements from TxTxT being the inputs and T being the output. Logical connectives would then be something similar to operations that you'd perform on the input, the component statement would itself be a function, and C would be the result. You're also mapping a set with 2^n elements, where n is the number of component statements, to a 2 element set with a composite statement.

I'm trying to consider the implications of all of this, but it's fairly fuzzy in my head. I'm mainly wondering about all this because I was just reviewing Cartesian products at the end of last chapter, and surprisingly component statements seem to be elements of such a product.

I'm curious if there is any sort of way to graph what I guess you could call a logic function (aka a composite statement).

My book doesn't really discuss any of this in the next few chapters, it might later on I'm not sure, so this is all conjecture. Any idea what type of math this would be a part of and what I should research to learn more about it?

Comment: This is certainly a valid view on the evaluation of a given formula. However, I don't see the point of your question. Instead of a graph, the *truth table* you already mentioned seems to be more appropriate to visualize this scenario and you're right that this table can be viewed as a function $\{t,f\}^n \to \{t,f\}$ and hence as a function whose domain is a Cartesian product.

Comment: I'm not sure in what direction I should take this realization to produce something new to understand. Also this should have some sort of effect on ways to view logic I'm simply unaware of. That's why I'm asking and hoping someone has that knowledge, or can help me figure out some new way of looking at things.

Comment: This is a sort of thought that feels very significant, but has very little bearing on mathematics.  Once you know the truth tables of whatever connectives you define, you can prove things about what compound statements you can  create.  In practice, you want a set of connectives that are functionally complete, and once you have that you don't care any more because you can create them all.

Comment: I suppose so. Its annoying when that happens, like when i realize the formula for the summation of a square n^2 (2n-1)in  highschool, its cool but doesn't lead to anything. The logical operations somewhat remind me of operations involving permutations, but I'll have to read a bit more about permutations before I can say for sure.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that a sentence $P$ is either true or false.  If all your sentences are that way, you are studying [propositional logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus) as opposed to [predicate logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_logic) which allows functions of input variables and quantification over those variables.  You are correct that a connective that takes $n$ inputs has $2^n$ possible output patterns.  One area of study in predicate logic is what sets of connectives are sufficient to express all $2^n$ output patterns.  It has been shown that NAND and NOR can express them all, meaning they are [functionally complete.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness)